# VBA -Column Insertion code Optimization

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Insert a column in the Worksheet,

Here Goes my code,

```
 Sheets(Currentsheetname).Range("A" & MyRow & ":B" & lastrow).Select
 .Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Is there a way to run this code, a bit faster. At the moment it is taking anything between 5-10 seconds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be faster: (never use `Select` and `Selection`)

```
Sheets(Currentsheetname).Range("A" & MyRow & ":B" & lastrow).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: Also worth noting, that Excel is spending some time repainting itself. OP should know about `Application.ScreenUpdating` toggle.